# Make Visual Studio 2013 use Self-Closing Tags for XAML

Tags: visual-studio, xaml, visual-studio-2013

I've just started messing around with WPF, and something I've noticed is that when writing in Visual Studio's XAML editor, tags that I'd like to be formatted as self-closing tags (for example `<Setter />`) always get auto-completed to have a separate closing tag, like `<Setter></Setter>`. Is there a way to change this behavior, or am I stuck reformatting those tags by hand?

Comment: There's an option for that. Check Tools -> Options or something.

Comment: I see an option to stop inserting closing tags altogether, but nothing that lets me make some tags self-closing.

Comment: I just wondered why one of my machines was generating self closing tags and another wasn't. Turns out it's a Resharper option! I didn't even notice until it wasn't there...

Answer (score 2):

I do not see one in the Visual Studio options but there is one in the Resharper options.

Resharper menu -> Code Editing -> XAML -> Editor -> Check "Always create self-closed tags in code completion"

Answer (score 0):

Just to expound on Fredrick's answer, for the Resharper setting, you need to ensure the option "Always create self-closed tags in code completion" is unchecked.
[image]