# How do I get Visual Studio Express 2013 to add a closing tag in XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2013

The question has been asked (sort of) here
[Make Visual Studio 2013 use Self-Closing Tags for XAML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18666520/make-visual-studio-2013-use-self-closing-tags-for-xaml)
but not really answered.
When I type in say StackPanel, I can't seem to get the UI to complete the closing tag.
Is there a command or keyboard sequence to do this?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself.

Type in the less-than sign (<kbd><</kbd>) and hit <kbd>enter</kbd>.

Comment: You should add this as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: I removed some fluff from the post to make it more clear that this is actually a solution you presented (this post came up in the flag queue for revision).

Comment: After Jeroen's edit this looks like a fine answer to me.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: Are you sure that by "right greater than symbol" (s)he means `<` (the left-pointing angle bracket / less-than sign) rather than `>` (the right-pointing angle bracket / greater-than sign)? The latter makes more sense IMHO.

Comment: @ruakh: `<` means the right value is greater than the left one. Which makes sense since it is the opening bracket and usually this is followed with an insertion of the entire closing tag. At least, this is how I remeber it working.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel: O.K., I've corrected the answer to say "less-than sign".

Comment: @TW: can you confirm that this is the way you meant your answer to be?

Answer (score 0):

There is also an option in the settings. Just search for tag in the settings and then Texteditor -> textspecific options(button). There you can set your default.